# How can I change signal amplitude in pyaudio using numpy?

Tags: numpy, volume, pyaudio

I'm currently using python 3.3 in combination with pyaudio and numpy. I took the example from the pyaudio website to play a simple wave file and send that data onto the default sound card.

Now I would like to change the volume of the audio, but when I multiply the array by 0.5, I get a lot of noise and distortion.

Here is a code sample:

```
while data != '':
decodeddata = numpy.fromstring(data, numpy.int16)
newdata = (decodeddata * 0.5).astype(numpy.int16)
stream.write(newdata.tostring())

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
```

How should I handle multiplication or division on this array without ruining the waveform?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that the source file's bitrate (24 bit) was not compatible with portaudio. After exporting to a 16 bit pcm file, the multiplication did not result in distortion.

To fix this for different typed files, it is necessary to check the bit depth and rescale correspondingly.

Comment: you tried to convert the decodeddata to float points to multiply the array by 0.5 and then convert back to short int ??